# CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout : Header plugin using swift and storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode-storyboard

So as the subject of this thread says it all, I am trying to implement this plugin : https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout using swift and the storyboard. I am have hard time using it. And I am kinda new to swift too. I really need help. If you guys have an example of implementation using this, with 2 different section and 2 different cell, it would be awesome! Or if you guys can help me implement it using 2 different section and 2 different cell.

Regards,

Hary.

EDIT 1: Made a progress. The example is working on my project. Didn't change a single line. So same example as given on the github, for the swift part. So now, I have to figure out, To add my custom cell already implemented in the storyboard.

FINAL EDIT : Made it work ! Silly me I guess..., mistake was coming from me.  Anyway If someone have the same issue. Send me a message. I'll try to answer !

Comment: Hi I'm looking for an example. Could you share the sample?

Comment: Yes, I can ! Sorry for the late response ! I'll send you the sample.